# The element of one div is going in to another div

Tags: html, css

```
 <main>
<!--      Carosel-->
      <div>
        <div class="carousel">


          <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left is-hidden">
              <img src="Image/left-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
          </button>

          <div class="carousel__track-container">
            <ul class="carousel__track">

              <li class="carousel__slide current-slide">
                <img class="carousel__image" src="Image/campbell-3ZUsNJhi_Ik-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
              </li>

              <li class="carousel__slide">
                <img class="carousel__image" src="Image/marc-kleen-8hU6vtwY8l8-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
              </li>

              <li class="carousel__slide">
                <img class="carousel__image" src="Image/marc-kleen-C9j8S_tIFLU-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>

          <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">
              <img src="Image/right-chevron-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
          </button>

          <div class="carousel__nav">
            <button class="carousel__indicator current-slide"></button>
            <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
            <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <section>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </section>
      <div>
        <h3 id="happy">Happy Clients</h3>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

That div with the happy clients is going inside the 3 dots
nav that i have like it isn't even there,
I can increase margin but that's a temporary solution,
can anyone tell me why the div with the h3 can not see the nav dots,
and here is my css.

[image: heading3 does not even see the nav dots like they are not even there]

```
.carousel{
    position:relative;
    height:800px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: red solid 2px;
}

.carousel__image{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}

.carousel__track-container{
    background: lightgreen;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.carousel__track{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.carousel__slide{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}

.carousel__button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: transparent;
    border:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__button--right{
    right:-40px;
}

.carousel__button--left{
    left:-40px;
}

.carousel__button img{
    width:20px;
}

.carousel__nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel__indicator{
    border:0;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    margin:0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__indicator.current-slide{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}

.is-hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

and that is my CSS that I used for html i tried to change it with margin and padding,
but i want to know why it does not see the nav dots at all

as u can see in the photo it stops below that image but that image and the nav dots are in the same div

Comment: I used an outline to debug your CSS, and yes happy client is in ..carousel__nav, I will try to see how to solve this

Comment: for me use `transform: translateY(2em);` , really I cant solve the bug, but visually using `translateY` is solve the problem

Comment: the thing is it looks like h3 doesn't even see the .carousel__nav

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you need to achieve

```js
$(".carousel__indicator").on("click", function() {
  $(".carousel__indicator").removeClass("current-slide");
  $(this).addClass("current-slide");
})
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red solid 2px;
}

.carousel__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel__track-container {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel__track {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__button--right {
  right: -40px;
}

.carousel__button--left {
  left: -40px;
}

.carousel__button img {
  width: 20px;
}

.carousel__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.carousel__indicator {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__indicator.current-slide {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <!--      Carosel-->
  <div>
    <div class="carousel">


      <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left is-hidden">
              <img src="Image/left-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
          </button>

      <div class="carousel__track-container">
        <ul class="carousel__track">

          <li class="carousel__slide current-slide">
            <img class="carousel__image" src="Image/campbell-3ZUsNJhi_Ik-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
          </li>

          <li class="carousel__slide">
            <img class="carousel__image" src="Image/marc-kleen-8hU6vtwY8l8-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
          </li>

          <li class="carousel__slide">
            <img class="carousel__image" src="Image/marc-kleen-C9j8S_tIFLU-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">
              <img src="Image/right-chevron-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
          </button>

      <div class="carousel__nav">
        <button class="carousel__indicator current-slide"></button>
        <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
        <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <h3 id="happy">Happy Clients</h3>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

but your code works. Maybe you need get right `z-index` for your navigation